# Union all, combining query results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union-all

I have following MySQL queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE record_id = 7 AND status = 'available' AND startdate >= '2015-05-02' AND startdate <= '2015-05-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE record_id = 7 AND status = 'available' AND startdate >= '2015-05-11' AND startdate <= '2015-05-12'
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries, instead of using `UNION ALL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` operator instead as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE record_id = 7 
AND status = 'available' 
AND ((startdate >= '2015-05-11' AND startdate <= '2015-05-12') or (startdate >= '2015-05-02' AND startdate <= '2015-05-09'))
```

Answer (score 2):

This schould work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE record_id = 7 AND status = 'available' AND 
   ((startdate >= '2015-05-02' AND startdate <= '2015-05-09') or (startdate >= '2015-05-11' AND startdate <= '2015-05-12'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an `OR` operator to get both date ranges:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   bookings 
WHERE  record_id = 7 AND
       status = 'available' AND 
       ((startdate >= '2015-05-02' AND startdate <= '2015-05-09') OR
        (startdate >= '2015-05-11' AND startdate <= '2015-05-12'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave this part:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE record_id = 7 AND status = 'available'
```

Add this:

```
AND ((startdate >= '2015-05-02' AND startdate <= '2015-05-09') OR (startdate >= '2015-05-11' AND startdate <= '2015-05-12'))
```

OR condition will return true if you get a true for the first and condition Or the second and condition

Also for those and conditions you are using you might want to take a look at the sql BETWEEN statement : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

You could also do this after your first part:

```
AND startDate >= '2015-05-02' AND startDate <= '2015-05-12' AND NOT startDate = '2015-05-10'
```

As you are using hard coded dates anyways and the only one in that range you don't need is the 10th of May